# Error while publishing my application to android market

Tags: android, google-play

when i am publishing my application to android market i am getting this error:Market does not accept apks signed with the debug certificate. Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.
i don't know how to solve it.
can any one help me?
Thanks in Advance
Aamirkhan I.

Comment: Please go read google documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own certificate to release your app in the Market. If you're using eclipse follow this.

- Right-click on your project > Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package...
- If your project is chosen, press next.
- Select: Create new keystore, set the path and password, press next
- Fill the form, (Validity = 1000), next
- Save the APK somewhere and press finish

**Important**
Save the keystore where you always find it and make a backup somewhere. You need this keystore to update your app. If you lose it you won't be able to update your app anymore. Not even Google can help you, if you lose it. So make a backup on your hard drive, online, external hard drive, ... This is a very important file.

But please use [this site](http://google.com) before you post something here.

Comment: Thanks for Reply let me try it

Comment: hi i have finish this all steps and i can see my key in my pc..now how can i see it in market?

Comment: your app is now signed with this key. you can now upload your app to the market. Next time you export your application choose "Use existing keystore" instead of creating a new one.

Comment: i have one qustion can i use single key to replease any application to the market?

Comment: Yes, you can use one keystore for multiple applications

Comment: hi still my application gets the error:Market does not accept apks signed with the debug certificate. Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5874/discussion-between-aamirpathan-and-bartinger)

Answer (score 0):

Check the link posted by Warpzit. The debug key store is used only for running application on the emulator. Please sign the application in the [release mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile) for uploading it to the android market.